# Collecting a Gmail Username when a Button is Pressed In Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a bathroom sign out sheet for my middle school students. I have created a Google App Script that Collects students names from a dropdown box and then logs the date and time. Everything seems to work great except when 500 students have access to the sheet at the same time. If a student selects their name it can possibly change before the script can be run. I would like to replace the dropdown box with a script that will automatically grab their Google User Name. Is there anyway this can be done? I am a novice programmer and tend to get things to work by tinkering around with it, but this seems to be above my head. Here is the Google Sheet and the Script is attached as well. Thanks in advance

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR36FnMTbJV4Nl8X8x_VyG107Y8Q-oCSgfG3ITEvaMjSraMv-bUH2u4FuWSE74Qg1gCrO5bg12pvawe/pubhtml

```
function clockIn() 
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

  //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();

  for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
  {
    // CHECK CLOCK IN
    if(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
    {
      Browser.msgBox("⚠️ You are Already Signed Out","Please Click the Returning to Classroom Button and then Try Again!",Browser.Buttons.OK);
      return;
    }
  }
  


//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//
  
// ADD CLOCK IN RECORD
  mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue()).setFontSize(12);
  mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
      
  

//CLEARCONTENTS
  {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
    sheet.getRange('B1:B2').clearContent();
  }
  if (mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() ==  mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
  {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⏰ Please Hurry Back! ⏰","Your Teacher is Waiting",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  } 
}


//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//



function clockOut() {
  
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

  //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
  
  var foundRecord = false;

  for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
  {
    // FIND CLOCK IN RECORD
    if(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Thank You! "," " ,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
      
      
      
      
      // UPDATE CLOCK IN RECORD
      mainSheet.getRange(j,3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
      var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() - mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getValue()) /(60*100*1000);
      mainSheet.getRange(j,4).setValue(totalTime.toFixed(2)).setNumberFormat("#0.00").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);  
      foundRecord = true;     
    }
  }
  

  
  //CLEARCONTENTS
  {
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
    sheet.getRange('B1:B2').clearContent();
  }



  // IF NO CLOCK IN RECORD

  if(foundRecord == false)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⚠️  No Record  ⚠️","You Might Have Forget to Sign Out?" ,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().     ButtonSet.OK);
     
  }
}
  
  
//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//

  
  
// CALL TOTAL HOURS
TotalHours();
  
function TotalHours()
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

  //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
  
  //DEFINE ARRAY
  var totals = [];
  
  //LOOP THROUGH ALL RATES
  for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
  {
    var rate = mainSheet.getRange(j, 4).getValue();
    var name = mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue();
    var foundRecord = false;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < totals.length; i++)
    {
       //FOUND RECORD ADD TO TOTAL
       if(name == totals[i][0] && rate != '')
       {         
         totals[i][1] =  totals[i][1] + rate;
         foundRecord = true;
       }
    }
    
    //ADD NEW RECORD, EXISTING RECORD NOT FOUND
    if(foundRecord == false && rate != '')
    {
      totals.push([name, rate]);
    }
  }
  
  //CLEAR DATA
  mainSheet.getRange("F5:G1000").clear();
  
  //DISPLAY TOTALS
  for(var i = 0; i < totals.length; i++)
  {
    mainSheet.getRange(5+i,6).setValue(totals[i][0]).setFontSize(12);
    mainSheet.getRange(5+i,7).setValue(totals[i][1]).setFontSize(12);  
  } 
}

//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//


function ClearCells() 
{
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DATASHEET');
 sheet.getRange('A5:G1000').clearContent();
}


//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//


function clearRange() 
{
  // replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  // replace 'dhrhrejYOURSHETIDerhe5j54j5j' with your actual sheet ID

  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1sjx0UAv73wiW-Jo1e8QWZuanjKK2tsjveVXjB1y_IHw").getSheetByName("DATASHEET");
  sheetActive.getRange('A5:G1000').clearContent();
}

//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//

``
```

Comment: I dare not dive deep into your code. Just in case: it makes sense to use `SpreasheetApp.flush()` command after the time consuming changes on the sheet. Especially if there are many users that make the changes simultaneously. And there is the https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock as well

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use a Google form?

Comment: Can you give an example of the Google Username? The easiest way is to get the current user's email address.

Comment: Google Form only tracks when the form is submitted. We have an issue with students being out for extended period of times. We did try it, but students would just change the times to make it look like they were only out for a few minutes. If there is something I am missing please let me know.

Comment: rocco.barletta@student.qacps.org would be an example of our student Gmail Usernames

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function getUserEmail() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

But it may not work all of the time because of a complex set of security protocols which I know nothing about.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pertaining to the email address of the user, you can use [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session?hl=en#getActiveUser()) which will give you the current user, then use [getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user?hl=en#getemail) to get the current user's email address. Similar to what @Cooper suggested

### You just need to use them in your `clockIn()` and `clockOut()`:

```
function clockIn() 
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

  //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();

  for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
  {
    // CHECK CLOCK IN
    if(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
    {
      Browser.msgBox("⚠️ You are Already Signed Out","Please Click the Returning to Classroom Button and then Try Again!",Browser.Buttons.OK);
      return;
    }
  }
  


//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//
  
// ADD CLOCK IN RECORD
  mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()).setFontSize(12);
  mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
      
  

//CLEARCONTENTS
  {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
    sheet.getRange('B1:B2').clearContent();
  }
  if (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() ==  Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
  {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⏰ Please Hurry Back! ⏰","Your Teacher is Waiting",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  } 
}


//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//



function clockOut() {
  
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

  //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
  
  var foundRecord = false;

  for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
  {
    // FIND CLOCK IN RECORD
    if(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Thank You! "," " ,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
      
      
      
      
      // UPDATE CLOCK IN RECORD
      mainSheet.getRange(j,3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
      var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() - mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getValue()) /(60*100*1000);
      mainSheet.getRange(j,4).setValue(totalTime.toFixed(2)).setNumberFormat("#0.00").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);  
      foundRecord = true;     
    }
  }
  

  
  //CLEARCONTENTS
  {
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
    sheet.getRange('B1:B2').clearContent();
  }



  // IF NO CLOCK IN RECORD

  if(foundRecord == false)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⚠️  No Record  ⚠️","You Might Have Forget to Sign Out?" ,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().     ButtonSet.OK);
     
  }
}
  
  
//_____
```

---

Another option is to use [promt dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#promptprompt,-buttons) to ask user to input their name when `clockIn()` or `clockOut()` was called. Then change the inputted name to capital letters.

### Your Code:

```
function clockIn() 
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

  //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Enter your name:',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var studentName;
  // Process the user's response.
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    Logger.log('The user\'s name is %s.', response.getResponseText());
     studentName = studentName.toUpperCase();
     studentName = response.getResponseText();
  } else {
     Logger.log('Request was cancelled.');
     return;
  }

  for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
  {
    // CHECK CLOCK IN
    if(studentName ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
    {
      Browser.msgBox("⚠️ You are Already Signed Out","Please Click the Returning to Classroom Button and then Try Again!",Browser.Buttons.OK);
      return;
    }
  }
  


//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//
  
// ADD CLOCK IN RECORD
  mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(studentName).setFontSize(12);
  mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
      
  

//CLEARCONTENTS
  {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
    sheet.getRange('B1:B2').clearContent();
  }
  if (studentName ==  studentName && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
  {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⏰ Please Hurry Back! ⏰","Your Teacher is Waiting",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  } 
}


//_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________//



function clockOut() {
  
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

  //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
  
  var foundRecord = false;
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Enter your name:',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var studentName;
  // Process the user's response.
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    Logger.log('The user\'s name is %s.', response.getResponseText());
     studentName = response.getResponseText();
     studentName = studentName.toUpperCase();
  } else {
     Logger.log('Request was cancelled.');
     return;
  }

  for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
  {
    // FIND CLOCK IN RECORD
    if(studentName ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Thank You! "," " ,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
      
      
      
      
      // UPDATE CLOCK IN RECORD
      mainSheet.getRange(j,3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
      var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() - mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getValue()) /(60*100*1000);
      mainSheet.getRange(j,4).setValue(totalTime.toFixed(2)).setNumberFormat("#0.00").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);  
      foundRecord = true;     
    }
  }
  

  
  //CLEARCONTENTS
  {
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
    sheet.getRange('B1:B2').clearContent();
  }



  // IF NO CLOCK IN RECORD

  if(foundRecord == false)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⚠️  No Record  ⚠️","You Might Have Forget to Sign Out?" ,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().     ButtonSet.OK);
     
  }
}
  
  
//_____
```

Comment: Just let me know if you encountered an issue and share a sample sheet. I wasn't able to test the proposed code due to lack of a sample sheet